# In SQL Server XML column how do I verify whether same value is present in more than one rows or not

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

In a SQL Server XML column, how do I verify whether same value is present in more than one rows or not?

Value could be dynamic - it's not fixed. Kindly refer to the table shown below, where Id column is Primary Key and in ExtendedData column  Tag value could be  in more than 1 rows.

Query to INSERT record into table

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Id BIGINT, AccountNumber int,ExtendedData XML)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Id,AccountNumber,ExtendedData) VALUES
(1, 14, '<ExtendedData> <Data>      <POLICYNBR>131313</POLICYNBR>      <ACCOUNTNBR>GGAHAHA</ACCOUNTNBR>      <ID>29499785613092400202</ID>  </Data></ExtendedData>'),
(2, 14, '<ExtendedData> <Data>      <POLICYNBR>131313</POLICYNBR>       <ACCOUNTNBR>GGAHAHA</ACCOUNTNBR>        <ID>29499785613092400202</ID>   </Data></ExtendedData>'),
(3, 14, '<ExtendedData> <Data>      <POLICYNBR>54555</POLICYNBR>        <ACCOUNTNBR>GGAHAHA</ACCOUNTNBR>        <ID>123485613092400202</ID>     </Data></ExtendedData>'),
(4, 13, '<ExtendedData> <Data>      <POLICYNBR>54555</POLICYNBR>        <ACCOUNTNBR>GGAHAHA</ACCOUNTNBR>        <ID>123485613092400202</ID> </Data></ExtendedData>')
```

**Expected result :-
If I pass Account id =14 then I should be able to see two records  in the response, because both for the accountId=14  tag has same value in ExtendedData column.**

This is my script : - But it seems to be its not working , it not giving the result which I am expecting.

```
select * from Table1 where AccountId =14 and 
ExtendedData.value('(/ExtendedData/Data/ID/text())[1]','varchar(10)') = select CAST(ExtendedData as XML).value('(/ExtendedData/Data/ID/)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') from Table1 where ExtendedData.value('(/ExtendedData/Data/ID/text())[1]','varchar(10)')
```

Please suggest me

Table name is `Table1`, and `Id` column is the primary key.
[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: as per the suggestion I have added all the required details.

Comment: Kumas, ##1,3, and 4 are missing.

Comment: I have updated - SQL server 2012

Comment: What about ##1,3?

Comment: Now I have added 1 and 3 - I am sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a `having`, after having pulled out the relevant id value

```sql
select t.AccountId, v.ExtendedId
from Table1 t
cross apply (values(
    ExtendedData.value('(/ExtendedData/Data/ID/text())[1]','varchar(10)')
) ) v(ExtendedId)
where AccountId = 14
group by t.AccountId, v.ExtendedId
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First for some re-usable sample data:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<ExtendedData>
  <Data>
    <PolNbr>123999</PolNbr>
    <ActNbr>ABCZZZ</ActNbr>
    <ID>555444</ID>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
<ExtendedData>
  <Data>
    <PolNbr>123999</PolNbr>
    <ActNbr>ABCXXX</ActNbr>
    <ID>555667</ID>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
<ExtendedData>
  <Data>
    <PolNbr>123111</PolNbr>
    <ActNbr>ABCZZZ</ActNbr>
    <ID>555667</ID>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
<ExtendedData>
  <Data>
    <PolNbr>123113</PolNbr>
    <ActNbr>ABCXXX</ActNbr>
    <ID>555666</ID>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>'

SELECT
  ID     = n.X.value('(ID)[1]','varchar(100)'),
  PolNbr = n.X.value('(PolNbr)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),
  ActNbr = n.X.value('(ActNbr)[1]','varchar(100)')
FROM        (VALUES(@xml)) AS f(X)
CROSS APPLY f.X.nodes('/ExtendedData/Data') AS n(X);
```

Note the output:

```
ID       PolNbr    ActNbr
-------- --------- ----------
555444   123999    ABCZZZ
555667   123999    ABCXXX
555667   123111    ABCZZZ
555666   123113    ABCXXX
```

Now we can adjust our query to identify any duplicate value:

```
--==== ID
SELECT      ID_Duplicates = nd.X
FROM        (VALUES(@xml)) AS f(X)
CROSS APPLY f.X.nodes('/ExtendedData/Data') AS n(X)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(n.X.value('(ID)[1]','varchar(100)'))) AS nd(X)
GROUP BY    nd.X
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1

--==== PolNbr
SELECT      PolNbr_Duplicates = nd.X
FROM        (VALUES(@xml)) AS f(X)
CROSS APPLY f.X.nodes('/ExtendedData/Data') AS n(X)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(n.X.value('(PolNbr)[1]','varchar(100)'))) AS nd(X)
GROUP BY    nd.X
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1;

--==== PolNbr
SELECT      ActNbr_Duplicates = nd.X
FROM        (VALUES(@xml)) AS f(X)
CROSS APPLY f.X.nodes('/ExtendedData/Data') AS n(X)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(n.X.value('(ActNbr)[1]','varchar(100)'))) AS nd(X)
GROUP BY    nd.X
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1;
```

**Results:**

```
ID_Duplicates
------------------------------------------
555667

PolNbr_Duplicates
------------------------------------------
123999

ActNbr_Duplicates
------------------------------------------
ABCXXX
ABCZZZ
```

Comment: Alan, it seems that the OP wants to compare XML in a column in its entirety, without any shredding.

Comment: Thank you Alan for the response. In my case as I have mentioned in the question, I need to find both the rows which as same value in <ID> tag inside ExtendedData column for the given AccountId. Could you please help me, how i can able to achieve as per my table data